# "Failed to load data" Message Showing After Clearing Search in Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

After performing a search on any of the sites in the Android app, when you click the `x` to clear the results and return to the active list of questions it displays the message `Failed to load data`. It doesn't seem to matter whether or not the search you perform returns any results or not. The message isn't displayed until after you click on the `x`, not after you perform the search. I'm not sure if there might *actually* be some issue occurring but it does not appear that there is since the list of questions is loading/loaded. As you can see in the first screenshot below, there are questions loaded behind the message. Tested on both good data and WiFi connections with same result.

I'm on version 0.1.70

**Update** based on Rafareino's comment (not able to reproduce on a 3G connection). I'm on a 4G connection and running Android version 4.1.2.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the left menu and go to any of the sites
2. Perform a search (doesn't seem to matter whether it actually returns any results or not. I searched "angular" on Stack Overflow)
3. After the search results are displayed, tap on the **`x`** to clear the search
4. After clearing the search, when the active list of questions is displayed again, the following message is displayed: `Failed to load data` as seen in the screenshot below

[image: Failed to load data message]

---

Here's a screenshot of the `x` I'm talking about, just to avoid any possibility of confusion:

[image: Search field with x outlined in red]

Comment: Include version, of app (menu -> help). I tryied it out an failed to reproduce the error. in 0.1.63

Comment: @Rafareino I did include the version...right below the first paragraph and above the steps to reproduce...

Comment: Oh, please forgive me for that, it seems that I'm are a sub release ahead of you, try update and try again.

Comment: @Rafareino people read over things haha, no worries. Just updated and still happens to me on version 0.1.63 though. Possibly you are using WiFi? Only thing that immediately comes to mind that might be different (other than more than likely the device)

Comment: Nope, I'm on a brazilian 3G connection (very low quality), and waited a lot to make sure that the message wasn't just delayed, so include your phone model, someone within development team should help you to provide some more info to them.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5 (on 3G connection), SE app 1.0.82 (beta)... come to think of it, the bug was reported even before public release, so I believe it has been fixed since then.